# Show that $\lim\limits_{z \to a}\frac{\log|f(z) - f(a)|}{\log |z - a|}$ is an integer.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in a neighborhood of $a$.  Show that $\lim\limits_{z \to a}\frac{\log|f(z) - f(a)|}{\log |z - a|}$ exists and is an integer.

We have $$\frac{\log|f(z) - f(a)|}{\log |z - a|} = \frac{\log|\frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z-a}| + \log |z-a| }{\log |z-a|} = \frac{\log | \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}|}{\log |z-a|} + 1$$ which goes to $\frac{\log |f'(a)|}{-\infty} + 1 = 1$ as $z$ goes to $a$, provided that $f'(a) \neq 0$. But what if $f'(a) = 0$?

Comment: A little bit of Taylor expansion helps. (And we should assume $f$ non-constant.)

Comment: not quite sure if this could work here: but what about l'Hopital - if I do this purely heuristically then, by assuming it is not a constant function, I get $1$ as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose a neighbourhood $\mathcal{V}$ of $a$ small enough that $f(z)-f(a)\neq0$ $\forall x\in\mathcal{V}-\{a\}$, then you can write
$$f(z)-f(a)=(z-a)^ng(z)$$
with $g(z)\neq0$ in $\mathcal{V}$.

From here we just have to put that on the limit,
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{\log|f(z)-f(a)|}{\log|z-a|}=\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{\log|z-a|^n|g(z)|}{\log|z-a|}=\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{n\log|z-a|+\log|g(z)|}{\log|z-a|}=$$
$$n+\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{|g(z)|}{-\infty}=n$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $a$, then we can expand $f$ in a Taylor series about $a$:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(z-a)^n.$$

Then

$$f(z) - f(a) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(z-a)^n = f'(a)(z-a) + \frac{1}{2} f''(a)(z-a)^2 + \cdots$$

If $f'(a) = \cdots = f^{(n)}(a) = 0$, then consider

$$\log|f(z) - f(a)| = \log\left|\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\right| + (n+1)\log|z-a|.$$

I hope you can take it from here.